# Oppo phones showing yellow line at Notification Bar

Tags: android, administrator, device-admin, device-policy-manager, oppo

I have an app which uses Administrator permission, In oppo phones if user provides Administrator permissions then Oppo phone is showing yellow line at Notification bar (Continuously flashing notification).

How can I prevent that notification in oppo phones.
refer Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: screenshot ????

Comment: Please add screenshot...

Comment: please check edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

I think in your phone developer mode is enabled.
So to disable it follow the step...
Go to settings -> Addition Settings -> Developer option
In Developer option switch the toggle button to off

Comment: This is not about developer option, It is about Device Administrator permission

Comment: Ok, Then find that app in install app section from setting and remove Administrative permission.
Or Another solution is that Opp phone has their own security app. From there you can find the permission, in it find that app and remove administrative  permission.

Comment: this is my own app and core functionality is dependent on this permission

Comment: But you can not stop flashing that bar because this is the Oppo inbuilt functionality for the security purpose for the user attention.

Comment: I can be, as there are few apps doing this.